# SHA-1 from UITextField xcode

Tags: ios, uitextfield, http-post, encode, sha1

Ok, so does anyone know of anyways to convert the input of the `UITextField` into a `SHA-1` string for me to use to in a `HTTP POST` method?
I already have it so it uploads the `UITextField` contents but is there anyway to pre-encode them before they get sent to the web?

Comment: Put the UITextField content into a NSString and codify with SHA-1.

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159785/iphone-sdk-how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-sha-1-and-sha-1-to-base64-for-wssec